# Only able to load 3900 of 1M records into Tableau from Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, tableau-api

I am not able to pull all the data to tableau from the Cassandra database. The table has 1 million records. I have tried with custom SQL and checked with top 3900 rows and it is loading in Tableau. However, all the records are not loading.

When I click on load getting error Tableau: [Datastax][CassandraODBC] (10) Error while executing a query in Cassandra[33559296] : Operation failed - received 0 responses and 1 failures.

We have installed Datastax Cassandra ODBC connector.

Answer (score 0):

For a query to return a failure, the most likely cause is that you're running into a tombstone problem.

When reading from a table, Cassandra iterates through the data and excludes deleted rows (marked with a tombstone) from being returned in the results. When a node has scanned over `tombstone_failure_threshold` tombstones (default is 100K), it will abort the read operation and return a `TombstoneOverwhelmingException`. You can confirm this by checking the logs on the Cassandra nodes.

There is no workaround for being able to read data from tables which have thousands of tombstones other than redesigning your data model. If you're interested, Ryan Svihla's blog post [Domain Modeling Around Deletes](https://foundev.medium.com/domain-modeling-around-deletes-1cc9b6da0d24) is a good resource. Cheers!